# Regex match Brackets Qt

Tags: regex, qt

i have a quick Question:

I have to program a Qt programm and there replace the not needed Brackets.
`STRING.replace(QRegExp("REGEX"), "");`

I need the Regex to match only brackets so i can replace them.

I have for example:
`12/((30)/(10/2))`

The i replace everything the Regex selected and as a Output i want:
`12/(30/(12/2))`

The Number in The middle of the Brackets could be:
`[0-9+\.+\,]{1,}`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted because I think it is a valid question. I personally gave an upvote, but once you find the proper regex, I would suggest to consider using QRegularExpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `\(([0-9.,]+)\)` and replace with `$1`.

This will capture all number which are directly surrounded by brackets, like `(30)` and replace it with the number itself.

Edit: you can see a demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/nJ4uT3). In the left tab it shows Match information.